# Create method doesn't store

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, backend

```
namespace Teatastic.Models
{
    public class Tea
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Name { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public double Price { get; set; }

        //Relationships
        public List<Function>? Functions { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public List<int> FunctionIds { get; set; }


        public int BrandId { get; set; }
        public Brand Brand { get; set; }

    }
}
```

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Teatastic.Models
{
    public class Brand
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Image? Logo { get; set; }

        public List<Tea>? Teas{ get; set; }

    }
}
```

Finally, this is the HttpPost method in the TeasController

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Price,FunctionIds,BrandId")] Tea tea)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (tea.Functions == null)
                {
                    tea.Functions = new List<Function>();
                }
                foreach (int FunctionId in tea.FunctionIds)
                {
                    tea.Functions.Add(_context.Function.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == FunctionId));
                }

                // Add brand to tea
                tea.Brand = _context.Brands.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == tea.BrandId);

                _context.Add(tea);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(tea);
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxoJz.png)

There is a one-to-many relationship between Tea and Brand (every tea has a brand, a brand can have multiple teas). I am trying to store this object in the database, but it appears that there is something wrong with the Brand.

Answer (score 0):

You may use .NET 6/.NET 7. From .NET 6 the **non-nullable property must be required**, otherwise the ModelState will be invalid.

Add `?` to your Brand property:

```
public class Tea
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public double Price { get; set; }

    //Relationships
    public List<Function>? Functions { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<int> FunctionIds { get; set; }


    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public Brand? Brand { get; set; }

}
```